# SAS: including macro reference in output?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS, is there a way to reference a macro in declaring an explicit output? It gives me an error when I use the code below, which tries to use the macro "&fname" as the output name declaring at the beginning of the data step. (As a bonus, is there a way to declare the names of the output data sets as some sort of loop, so I don't have to type cd2002, cd2003, etc..).

```
data cd2002 cd2003 cd2004 cd2005;
    set cd;
    do i = 2002 to 2005;
        %let fname=cats(cd,i);
        if year=i then do; output &fname; end;
    end
run;
```

Comment: I am curious as to why the data needs to be split apart ?  WHERE can select specific years or a range of years, BY and CLASS statements can split the data on the year in other DATA and PROC steps.

Comment: I needed to load the data into MATLAB, and the data set was too big to load in as one big step. It seemed easier to export year by year.

Comment: Is MATLAB going to load SAS datasets? If you are going to generate CSV files to load into MATLAB then you can dynamically generate the filename using the FILEVAR= option on the FILE statement.

Comment: And another good option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572166/sas-macro-generating-data-driven-subset-data-files?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a macro routine.  This is a way to have SAS "write" code for you.  There is a macro processor that expands the code and then submits it to the main interpreter.

```
%macro split_cd(to,from);
%local i;
data
   %do i=&to %to &from;
      cd&i
   %end;
;
set cd;
%do i=&to %to &from;
      if year=&i then output cd&i;
%end;
run;
%mend;
```

Use the `mprint` option to see what code was generated and sumbitted:

```
options mprint;
%split_cd(2002,2005)
```